# Una forma más elegante o correcta de llamar a una función que devuelve una promesa en un servicio desde un componente

Tags: angular, firebase

Tengo una función que devuelve una promesa en un servicio que crea un usuario en Firebase con la librería "AngularFire".

```js
  crearUsuario = (email: string, password: string)=>{

      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

          let obtejoRespuesta: Respuesta;
          
          
          console.log("Vamos a crear un usuario");
          this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(res=>{

            
            obtejoRespuesta = { 
              valor: true,
              comentario: "Se ha guardado ok"
            };
            
            resolve(obtejoRespuesta);
            
          }).catch(err=>{

            let obtejoRespuesta = {
              valor: false,
              comentario: "No se ha guardado ok. Error-->" + err
            };

            reject(obtejoRespuesta);
            
            
          });
        
        
        });
  }
```

Desde el componente se llama a esa promesa, en el resolve y en reject se devuelve un objeto.

- Ésta es la forma correcta de para crear un usuario en Firebase?
- Hay alguna forma más elegante o con más ventajas?

```js
 crearUsuario(email: string, password: string)
  {
    
    this.miservicio.crearUsuario(email, password).then((response: any)=>{
      console.log(response.comentario);
    }

    ).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error.comentario);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Creo que andas creando una promesa innecesaria, has probado hacer el return en la parte `this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` sin todo lo demás y dejas el llamado en el component como lo tienes, pero simplemente colocas un console.log donde imprimar en consola la respuesta original a ver que te llega, si no vas a usar nada de allí simplemente desde el componente creas el objeto que creaste en el servicio y ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que si hablas de mejorar un poco lo que haces, puedes reducir un poco la codificación removiendo la promesa que creas. Ya que el propio servicio que ejecutas es una promesa.

Entonces podríamos dejar el servicio de la siguiente manera:

```
crearUsuario = (email: string, password: string) => {
  return this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

Y el componente quedaría así:

```
crearUsuario(email: string, password: string) {
  this.miservicio.crearUsuario(email, password).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Creo que es lo mismo en menos lineas de código. Ya en el componente según la respuesta así haces lo que requieras.

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Ahora entiendo: si pongo un "return" en la función del servicio, dicho return me devuelve una promesa en si, y luego ya en la función del componente manejo dicha promesa con un ""then().catch()". Entiendo que "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" me devuelve una promesa en sí, creo que  hay otras funciones de Direbase  que me devuelven un observable, entonces en ese caso me tendré que subscribir a ese observable, es así?

Comment: @casiopea2000 hay funciones que retornan un observable, pero puedes hacer exactamente lo mismo. La retornas como lo hice en el servicio. Pero en el componente donde llamas la función si deseas trabajar con promesas solo debes colocar la funcion().toPromise().then().cath(). Ejemplo supongamos que crearUsuario retorna un observable entonces sería  `this.miservicio.crearUsuario(email, password).toPromise().then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: con el "toPromise()" lo que haces es convertir en una promesa el retorno de una función del servicio que retorna un observable?